# Cassandra down, but with no info in system.log

Tags: cassandra, crash, jvm

Cassandra suddenly crashed at 9:54, but with no info after 9:52 in system.log.
[cassandra-system.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Zqv.png)

Our Cassandra version is 3.11.10, and we run instaclustr/cassandra-exporter as a standalone server to monitor Cassandra, but we can't get any abnormal info to find the reason.
Here is the change in JVM HEAP usage.
[JVM HEAP usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZNqd.png)

We never knew exactly why.

At first we thought it was OOM-kill, but there was no kill process in /var/log/message. At the same time, vm.max_map_count = 1048575 was modified according to the WARN information when starting Cassandra. Now there are still these WARN messages, it is not known whether it is related to Cassandra crash.
[Setup Cassandra WARNING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPVXN.png)

Who can help to give some ideas or solutions, thank you!

Comment: Please just post (and format) error/warning messages instead of putting them into an image on an external site.

Answer (score 0):

Given the warning messages, it looks like there are several settings that are not up-to-spec on this node. This doc has some good guidance on what those should be: [Apache Cassandra® 3.0 - Recommended production settings](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html)

You'll want to go through that doc and make sure that the recommended settings are being applied. Specifically, I'd recommend disabling swap space.

Edit `/etc/fstab` and comment-out the line(s) containing the word "swap." That will take effect after a reboot, so run `sudo swapoff -a` to disable it for the current session.

Also, that's quite a substantial "local pause" time. Are there any GC.log files to check? Maybe turn on GC logging to see what's going on there. That could also be the result of a really terrible query.

Anyway, go through the doc linked above, restart the node, and see if there's any improvement. I'd start there.

Comment: Well, thank you so much for your help! I will follow the above link first. And later to see whether Cassandra will be down again.